# Run a Java class on Eclipse automatically without pressing the "run" button

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm programing  for a Socket(Client-Server) ,I want my client run automatically after turning on my Server without pressing the "run" button at the class of Client.
Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Braj what code? OP wants/needs a way to execute two classes almost at the same time...

Comment: Why do you want your client to run automatically?

Comment: I'm programing a application of reading the RFID tags so I want it read the RFID tags continously then sending data to the Server.i want to make it run on a pc without pressing the "run" button to start reading.

Comment: Create a shell script that runs on the PC start up.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't directly entail using Eclipse, you can create a shell script that starts first your server (possibly checking that your server ran properly) and then your client.  That is the simplest way to run the client upon starting the server.

Another approach is to create a Java class in Eclipse that successively starts the server and client modules.